# mcisendstring returning null string

Tags: c, winapi, mci

I'm stuck trying to retrieve the song length of a music I was able to open and play with WINMM's function mciSendString();

```
char szCmd[128];
char szResponse[128] = {0};
sprintf_s( szCmd, 128, "status my_alias length");

dwRet =  mciSendString( (LPCSTR)szCmd, szResponse, 0, NULL );
```

Even though no error code is returned, the szResponse string always return NULL.

I tried setting the time format to milliseconds, with

```
"set my_alias time format to milliseconds"
```

but got no luck as well.

Comment: [mciSendString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757161.aspx): *"**cchReturn**: Size, in characters, of the return buffer specified by the lpszReturnString parameter."*

Comment: You told Windows you wanted a 0 character reply and it did exactly what you asked. :)

Comment: The `(LPCSTR)` cast looks very wrong. Use wide characters (`wchar_t` / `swprintf_s()` or `mciSendStringA()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, I was passing 0 in the third parameter of mciSendString, which is the size of the return buffer specified by the second parameter.